# Using Additional Data on Intermediate Table with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm working on a project that is used to input information about a product into a document.  One section has a form that can be filled out as many times as needed for a particular product.  The information on this form is then available to be shared on multiple related documents.  A typical many-to-many situation.  The difference is, on the intermediate table, I want to store specific information for that form entry for that specific document.

Here are some table definitions to illustrate the point:

```
Document(
  Id int identity(1,1),
  Name nvarchar(256)
)

Form(
  Id int identity(1,1),
  FormData nvarchar(max)
)

DocumentForms(
  DocumentId int,
  FormId int,
  DocumentFormNumber varchar(64)
)
```

And some classes:

```
public class Document{
  public int Id { get; protected set; }
  protected IList<Form> Forms { get; set; }
}

public class Form {
  public int Id { get; protected set; }
  public string DocumentFormNumber { get; set; }
  public string FormData { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to create a mapping that supports reading the additional data when reading forms as part of the many to many relationship with Document?  Do I need to use a stored procedure when loading data with the many to many relationship?  I still need to be able to load the Form objects without them being a part of a document, but once they are added to the document, I need them to have a number that is generated based on some simple rules.  But that number is obviously document specific.  So while the next document might use the same Form data, it needs a new number.

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer in a blog post by Billy McCafferty [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2008/07/11/when-to-use-many-to-one-s-vs-many-to-many-with-nhibernate.aspx).